# Users cant nslookup my windows server 2019 domain

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, domain

when i ipconfig /all in my server i see this:

```
IPv6 Address. : 2804:7f0:6880:a506:463a:e968:cf0e:177d(Preferred)
IPv6 Address. : 2804:7f0:6880:e6d7:1e98:ecff:fe2c:2398(Preferred)
```

the first one is the one i want, i manually configured it on the control panel, but for some reason the mere existense of the second one is messing with my domain, the users cant nslookup my.domain with the 177d ipv6 configured but they can with the 2398 configured, and when pinging my.domain the answer comes from 2398 and not from the static reliable 177d.

I already tried the following to get rid of this temporary ipv6:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled
```

When deleting with `netsh interface ipv6 delete` another ipv6 comes and prevents users from acessing the domain, how do I force the server to only have one ipv6?

Comment: Are you sure your static configuration is correct? If you are using /64 nets, the addresses is in different networks. If you're not using /64 nets, stop what you're doing and switch to /64. And why only one IP on IPv6? That's not how things are intended to be with IPv6. That's IPv4-thinking.

Comment: even if, on a network a static ip for a dns is mostly suggested regardless if v4 or v6 is used.

Comment: i am sure my static configuration is correct, in the server i have this when i "netsh interface ipv6 show address": Manual Preferred infinite infinite 2804:7f0:6880:a506:463a:e968:cf0e:177d
And when i ipconfig /all in the client i see this: 
 Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 2804:7f0:6880:a506:463a:e968:cf0e:177d
                                                 192.168.15.100
which is precisely my server ip's

Comment: That doesn't mean it's correct. What is the configuration of your RA on the subnet? You configuring the wrong subnet would explain why things do not work, but works with the autoconfigured one...

Comment: @djdomi unless you use privacy extension, IPv6 addresses are predictable and will not change. They're essentially prefix + mac-address. The temporary addresses are random, but are only used for outgoing connections and not added to DNS.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity: Are there multiple VLANs on the switch port that the server is connected to?

Comment: @u1686_grawity i have yet to learn how to configure a vlan so i believe there are none, unless windows server makes it automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the first one is the one i want, i manually configured it on the control panel, but for some reason the mere existense of the second one is messing with my domain, the users cant nslookup my.domain with the 177d ipv6 configured but they can with the 2398 configured, and when pinging my.domain the answer comes from 2398 and not from the static reliable 177d.

The addresses:

```
2804:7f0:6880:a506:463a:e968:cf0e:177d
2804:7f0:6880:e6d7:1e98:ecff:fe2c:2398
```

The first 64 bits is `2804:7f0:6880:e6d7` or `2804:7f0:6880:a506`. These two addresses *are in different subnets*. That's by all means a valid configuration - albeit a strange one. If you by any chance has a subnet that is *not* /64, stop what you're doing; that's a likely source of your problems!

Additionally you mention that things *don't* work when you use the first address - which is manually configured - but it *works* when you use the second one. This indicates that the problem is *indeed* that you have configured the wrong address!

Try using `2804:7f0:6880:e6d7:463a:e968:cf0e:177d`, which is inside the same subnet as the automatically assigned one.

Comment: It immediately worked thank you so much, i clearly need to study some ipv6 to do this

Comment: I would suggest avoiding static configuration.

Comment: Why ? Shouldn't my servers IP be static for the clients to always know how to find it ?

Comment: If a host doesn't change MAC (SLAAC) or DUID (DHCPv6) the address *will* be static.